# Как правильно разбить таблицы

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, проектирование

в двух словах, есть сервис по бронированию экскурсий, экскурсия привязывается к региону и одна экскурсия может быть привязана к нескольким регионам. В каждом регионе есть свой список отелей из которых забирают клиентов и везут на экскурсию

у меня есть таблицы:

```
1) regions - id, title
2) excursions - id, title, text
2) hotels - id, title
```

Вот дальше я запутался как правильно и лучше разбить, чтобы поиск был либо по региону, либо по региону и отелю к нему привязанному

Пока вот так сделал

```
1) excursion_region - id, excursion_id, region_id
2) excursion_region_hotel - id, excursion_region_id, hotel_id
```

Но что-то такая структура меня смущает и мне кажется очень сложная логика. Буду рад профессиональному совету, спасибо

Comment: Проделайте качественный анализ предметной области и постройте ER-диаграмму. Потом на основании диаграммы уже создавайте таблицы. А стряпать таблицы по некоему мистическому наитию - это совершенно безнадёжное занятие.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первая расшивка (many-to-many) правильная, вторая - нет. Расшивка на расшивку - это какое-то извращение.

Как я понял, эти таблицы уже существуют:

- regions - id, title
- excursions - id, title, text
- hotels - id, title

Добавляйте ещё две расшивки, и будет ок:

- region_excursion - id, region_id, excursion_id
- region_hotel - id, region_id, hotel_id